# How to create a custom keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I tried following [this](https://tuomassalmi.com/tech/custom-keyboard-variant/) tutorial, but it just doesn't work.

Basically I pasted this into /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "wlasna" {

    include "pl"
    name[Group1]= "Russian (custom)";

    key <LatQ> { [    Cyrillic_shcha,    Cyrillic_SHCHA  ] };
    key <LatZ> { [       Cyrillic_ze,       Cyrillic_ZE,    Cyrillic_zhe,      Cyrillic_ZHE  ] };
    key <LatS> { [       Cyrillic_es,       Cyrillic_ES,    Cyrillic_sha,      Cyrillic_SHA  ] };
    key <LatA> { [        Cyrillic_a,        Cyrillic_A,     Cyrillic_ya,       Cyrillic_YA  ] };
    key <LatW> { [       Cyrillic_ve,       Cyrillic_VE  ] };
    key <LatC> { [      Cyrillic_tse,      Cyrillic_TSE,    Cyrillic_che,      Cyrillic_CHE  ] };
    key <LatX> { [ Cyrillic_hardsign, Cyrillic_HARDSIGN  ] };
    key <LatD> { [       Cyrillic_de,       Cyrillic_DE  ] };
    key <LatE> { [       Cyrillic_ie,       Cyrillic_IE,      Cyrillic_e,        Cyrillic_E  ] };
    key <LatV> { [ Cyrillic_softsign, Cyrillic_SOFTSIGN  ] };
    key <LatF> { [       Cyrillic_ef,       Cyrillic_EF  ] };
    key <LatT> { [       Cyrillic_te,       Cyrillic_TE  ] };
    key <LatR> { [       Cyrillic_er,       Cyrillic_ER  ] };
    key <LatN> { [       Cyrillic_en,       Cyrillic_EN  ] };
    key <LatB> { [       Cyrillic_be,       Cyrillic_BE  ] };
    key <LatH> { [       Cyrillic_ha,       Cyrillic_HA  ] };
    key <LatG> { [      Cyrillic_ghe,      Cyrillic_GHE  ] };
    key <LatY> { [     Cyrillic_yeru,     Cyrillic_YERU  ] };
    key <LatM> { [       Cyrillic_em,       Cyrillic_EM  ] };
    key <LatJ> { [   Cyrillic_shorti,   Cyrillic_SHORTI  ] };
    key <LatU> { [        Cyrillic_u,        Cyrillic_U,     Cyrillic_yu,       Cyrillic_YU  ] };
    key <LatK> { [       Cyrillic_ka,       Cyrillic_KA  ] };
    key <LatI> { [        Cyrillic_i,        Cyrillic_I  ] };
    key <LatO> { [        Cyrillic_o,        Cyrillic_O  ] };
    key <LatL> { [       Cyrillic_el,       Cyrillic_EL  ] };
    key <LatP> { [       Cyrillic_pe,       Cyrillic_PE  ] };
};
```

(If you are wondering what I was trying to achieve - phonetic keyboard, **but** with all non letter symbols in the same place as in my native language (polish), **and** with "special" symbols as alternate character on keys closest to them in pronunciation, not just on random keys (for example <kbd>A key</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> - <kbd>я</kbd>, <kbd>ю</kbd> on <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ш</kbd> on <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>, etc.).)

Then I put this into /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml:

```
 <variant>
   <configItem>
     <name>wlasna</name>
     <description>Russian (custom)</description>
   </configItem>
 </variant>
```

And then I restarted computer, and... I still can't find my custom layout in layouts' list :/

Did I do something wrong, or is just this tutorial outdated, and I should use another one? Because I can't spot any error.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. :)

Please note that you need to put it in `evdev.xml` as a variant of the Russian layout, i.e. somewhere below this part:

```
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>ru</name>
        <!-- Keyboard indicator for Russian layouts -->
        <shortDescription>ru</shortDescription>
        <description>Russian</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>rus</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList>
```

`evdev.xml` could be found in `usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` in my case.